# keep number always in first group

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm trying to create a group that holds the number from the multi line list below.
The regex seems to be working here - https://regex101.com/r/tS5qV5/1 but when i run it with nodejs it doesn't give me the right output. Any ideas what could be wrong?

**RegEx**

```
/(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,2}){0,1})?(km\/h|m\/h)?(?:(?:audi|bmw)(?:\scoupe)*)*/gmi
```

**Text**

```
2.33 km/h
km/h 2.33
```

**Result**

`2.33 km/h` -> `[ '2.33', '', 'km/h', '' ]`

`km/h 2.33` -> `[ 'km/h', '', '2.33', '' ]`

**Expected for both lines**

`[ '2.33', 'km/h']`

**Node code**

```
var match  = req.match(/(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,2}){0,1})?(km\/h|m\/h)?(?:(?:audi|bmw)(?:\scoupe)*)*/gmi);

console.log(match);
```

Comment: Please show the precise node code you are using.

Comment: added the node code @torazaburo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a branch reset feature that is *not supported by JS regex engine*.

You can only use capturing within a regular grouping construct, and then adding some JS logic to get your resulting array contain the values you need:

```
/(?:(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)\s*(k?m\/h)|(k?m\/h)\s*(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?))?(?:(?:audi|bmw)(?:\scoupe)*)*/gi
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eL8lE3/1), and below is the code that will help you build the right result:

```js
var re = /(?:(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)\s*(k?m\/h)|(k?m\/h)\s*(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?))?(?:(?:audi|bmw)(?:\scoupe)*)*/gi; 

function testResults(str) {
 var res = [];
 while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    if (m[1]) {
      res.push(m[1], m[2]); //First goes Group 1, then Group 2
    } else if (m[3]) {
      res.push(m[4], m[3]); // Swapping to ensure the same order
    } else if (m[0]) {
      res.push(m[0]);
    }
 }
 return res;
}

var s = '2.33 km/h audi bmw coupe coupe'; 
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>"  + s + "<br/>" + JSON.stringify(testResults(s), 0, 4) + "</pre>";
s = 'km/h 2.33'; 
document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>" + s + "<br/>" + JSON.stringify(testResults(s), 0, 4) + "</pre>";

// Results:
// '2.33 km/h audi bmw coupe coupe' => ["2.33","km/h", "audi", "bmw coupe coupe"]
// 'km/h 2.33'                      => ["2.33","km/h"]
```

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thanks for the answer. I'm surprised that JS doesn't provide what seems to be an important regex feature. Anyways, I wanted to know if I have the `audi` or `bmw coupe coupe` strings before the first group or between the first and second (`number` and `measurement` or vice versa). Do i need to have a `switch` with cases that check against a shorter regex if the group is a number or speed measurement? So the flow will be to define the groups and then loop to find out what they are?

Comment: As you see you can only capture the optional substrings and then use some logic to check which ones matched. If you want to use separate, shorter patterns, it can also be a work around. Maybe even a better one

Comment: I think that provides more flexibility and it would potentially be faster if I use strict matching with `^` and `$`. Thanks for the answer. I've started looking into regex and, as everything, knowing the limitations are crucial to solving a problem.